# create importable Python module in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, containers, virtualization

How would I import a Python module that is running in a docker container? Is this even possible from outside the container?

Use case: I want to use a difficult to install - at least on Windows - Python module independently on the actual platform.

Comment: I'm guessing this won't work. Your system (Windows) can't simply set it's PYTHONPATH to the container or anything. Plus there will be binary incompatibility for anything that's compiled in your docker container. I'd suggest a different approach for your problem.